# Filter within column in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a table name: **Sample** in MySql Database
Inside this table, there is particular column "**Claims**"
Within this column the data starts from Payment

Example,
[image]

Can you please let me know how to filter out data that has only "BSA" and "TLS" and "SSL"

Comment: MySql databse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Sample
where Claims like '%BSA%' or Claims like '%TLS%' or Claims like '%SSL%'
```